# Public URLs For Objects In Bluemix Object Storage Service

Tags: ibm-cloud, openstack-swift, object-storage

I would like to upload a number of photos to the Bluemix Object Storage service and then display them in a web app.  Right now a GET request to the photo in the object storage container requires and auth token.  Is there any way I can create a public URL to the object that would not require an auth token for a GET request?

I see there is an option of creating temporary URLs to objects but I don't want the URL to be temporary I want it to live forever.  Is the only option to create a long lived temporary URL?

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to do this is to modify the container ACL.  You cannot do this via the Bluemix UI currently but you can using the [Swift REST API](http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-objectstorage-v1.html#createContainer).  For example, to change the container ACL so anyone can read objects in the container you can issue the following `PUT` request.

```
curl -X PUT "https://dal.objectstorage.open.softlayer.com/v1/AUTH_123/mycontainer" \
    -H "X-Auth-Token: token123" \
    -H "X-Container-Read: .r:*"
```

Comment: How do I get X-Auth-Token for a free plan

Comment: `you can issue the following PUT request` ... `curl -X GET` ... so is it `GET` or `PUT`?

Comment: To get the auth token, there is an extra step which involves exchanging the user name and password for a token. The instructions here work well, but I had to use curl -v to get the token from the response headers: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/ObjectStorage/os_authenticate.html

Comment: Another useful hint when getting the token, and following the instructions in the previous link, is that there a lot of endpoints in the returned json. The one that's needed is the one with type 'object-store' and name 'swift', and the particular endpoint in that group is the 'public' one for the desired region.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a old post but with the help of Ryan Baxter and Object storage documentation in IBM I could resolve the Issue
Finally these too commands saved the day

First use swift and change access control of container

```
swift post container-name --read-acl ".r:*,.rlistings"
```

Next Using Curl Configure Container to a particular Url for accessing Files

```
curl -X GET " https://<access point>/<version>/AUTH_projectID/container-name" -H "X-Auth-Token:<auth token>"     -H "X-Container-Read: .r:*,.rlistings"
```

And also very grateful for the help provided by Alex da Silva

Answer (score 0):

Now BlueMix has an S3 endpoint capability. You can use curl or any other langage for exemple here is an boto3 that will upload an object, make it public and and some metadata : 
( the function is using a json file on which you store the credentials and it uses 3 variables that are used in the global app : currentdirpath,ImagesToS3,ImageName )

```
def UploadImageDansBucket (currentdirpath,ImagesToS3,ImageName) :
    currentdirpath = 'path/to/your/dir/current'
    ImagesToS3 = ' /path/of/your/object/'
    ImageName = 'Objectname'
    with open("credentials.json", 'r') as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())
        bucket_target = data["aws"]["targetBucket"]
        print ('Open Connection to the bucket in the cloud..........')  

        s3ressource = boto3.resource(
            service_name='s3', 
            endpoint_url= data["aws"]["hostEndPoint"],
            aws_access_key_id= data["aws"]["idKey"],
            aws_secret_access_key=data["aws"]["secretKey"],
            use_ssl=True,
            )
        s3ressource.meta.client.meta.events.unregister('before-sign.s3', fix_s3_host)
        s3ressource.Object(bucket_target, 'hello.txt').put(Body=b"I'm a test file")
        s3ressource.Object(bucket_target, 'bin.txt').put(Body=b"0123456789abcdef"*10000)
        fn = "%s%s" % (ImagesToS3,ImageName)
        data = open(fn, 'rb')
        #s3ressource.Bucket(bucket_target).put_object(Key=fn, Body=data)
        now = datetime.datetime.now()  # on recupere la date actuelle 
        timestamp = time.mktime(now.timetuple())  # on effectue la convertion
        timestampstr = str (timestamp)
        s3ressource.Bucket(bucket_target).upload_file(fn,ImageName, ExtraArgs={ "ACL": "public-read", "Metadata": {"METADATA1": "a" ,"METADATA2": "b","METADATA3": "c", "timestamp": timestampstr },},)
```