# How to access files in container in Object Storage Service in Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage, ibm-cloud-tools

1. How can I access files by url in Bluemix Object Storage?
2. Is there a way to make the container public?
3. How can I access the file in Object Storage just by typing the url
   in the browser?
4. How can I retrieve an image by url to display it in html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally these too commands saved the day

First use swift and change access control of container

```
swift post container-name --read-acl ".r:*,.rlistings"
```

Next Using Curl Configure Container to a particular Url for accessing Files

```
curl -X GET " https://<access point>/<version>/AUTH_projectID/container-name" -H "X-Auth-Token:<auth token>"     -H "X-Container-Read: .r:*,.rlistings"
```

And also very grateful for the help provided by Alex da Silva

Answer (score 1):

You can create a temporary URLs using the swift command line to provide public access to your Object Storage files.

First you have to set the swift CLI, you can find steps on this [link](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/ObjectStorage/objectstorge_usingobjectstorage.html#using-swift-cli).

After you have swift cli configured for your environment you can run the following commands to create temporary URLs for your files:

```
swift stat
```

to locate your account field (starts with AUTH_)

```
swift post -m "Temp-URL-Key:<key>"
```

to set a secret key

```
 swift stat
```

to verify a secret key was created

```
swift tempurl GET <seconds> <path> <key>
```

to create the temporary URL

You can then access the file via the following URL:

```
https://<access point>/<API version>/AUTH_<project ID>/<container namespace>/<object namespace>
```

Complete details are available in the Object Storage documentation [here](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/ObjectStorage/objectstorge_usingobjectstorage.html#create-temporary-url).

Comment: I believe if you use 0 (or a negative number) it will never expire, but I never tried that.

Comment: Is there a way I can access the entire container and then based on name of the file I can access the file.so I can view my files directly by giving url of container and append file name In java code.Or any other alternative to achieve this?

Comment: Not sure I completely understood the question above, but maybe you can try this solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36338324/public-urls-for-objects-in-bluemix-object-storage-service to set your container as public

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a comment on that here : 
[Public URLs For Objects In Bluemix Object Storage Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36338324/public-urls-for-objects-in-bluemix-object-storage-service/41258502#41258502)
BlueMix is still using swift but S3 API is the most reliable.

So to answere your questions :

```
How can I access files by url in Bluemix Object Storage?
```

after uploading an image ( for example), you have to use a tool that can access your image and make it public ( it will add a public acl in the properity of the object ). you can use Cloudberry for example or S3 Browser and use the functionality " make public ".

```
Is there a way to make the container public?
```

Your contenair will run in bluemix, but the service can create a public URL. yes.

```
How can I access the file in Object Storage just by typing the url in the browser?
```

here is an example of an image I made public on my object store : 
https://s3-api.dal-us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/mourad-bucket-rasp-1/OBAMA.jpg 
You can do this using any browser after adding the acl to "public read"
( again, if you use python and boto3 sdk, see my post here : [Public URLs For Objects In Bluemix Object Storage Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36338324/public-urls-for-objects-in-bluemix-object-storage-service/41258502#41258502) )

```
How can I retrieve an image by url to display it in html?
```

Several way to do that, since, it has now a public Url and the first part of the ul will not change, only name of your object will change, just call your URL using variable ( like bucket, names etc.. )

the complete API reference has been released and it is [Here](https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/crs-api-reference.html)