# Access Public URLs from IBM Cloud storage

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, openstack-swift, object-storage

I have created a IBM cloud Object storage service and i have created objects i.e image files in it.

I am looking for the steps to access the images as public URLs. I did some initial research and found there are cURL commands using swift Client to do this.

Reference  links 
[How to access files in container in Object Storage Service in Bluemix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679478/how-to-access-files-in-container-in-object-storage-service-in-bluemix?noredirect=1&lq=1) AND
[Public URLs For Objects In Bluemix Object Storage Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36338324/public-urls-for-objects-in-bluemix-object-storage-service)

from the above links, it says the following steps

1. Set up the swift CLI . Can you link me the steps to set up Swift CLI ? ( the link in the reference link dosen't work anymore ).

2.Change the container ACL to read with following `PUT` request

```
curl -X PUT "https://dal.objectstorage.open.softlayer.com/v1/AUTH_123/mycontainer" \
    -H "X-Auth-Token: token123" \
    -H "X-Container-Read: .r:*"
```

But i am not sure what to input on `X-Auth-Token` header ? i have the following information from the service credentials of COS.

```
{
  "apikey": "X7aDm6yu123123hXwqvq1231232HgOtIGeZiAOEg",
  "endpoints": "https://cos-service.bluemix.net/endpoints",
  "iam_apikey_description": "Auto generated apikey during resource-key operation for Instance - crn:v1:bluemix:public:cloud-object-storage:global:a/f9aabca54c702be8386b2a3f9815b4e4:d145a33e-e8b1-446f-a87d-69431eaec0b1::",
  "iam_apikey_name": "auto-generated-apikey-bed16ed5-1373-47bc-b268-5e0f521bc802",
  "iam_role_crn": "crn:v1:bluemix:public:iam::::serviceRole:Writer",
  "iam_serviceid_crn": "crn:v1:bluemix:public:iam-identity::a/f9aabca54c702be8386b2a3f9815b4e4::serviceid:ServiceId-36c373a0-4bb9-4316-bc4b-86ea4c98dcd7",
  "resource_instance_id": "crn:v1:bluemix:public:cloud-object-storage:global:a/f9aabca54c702be8386b2a3f9815b4e4:d145a33e-e8b1-446f-a87d-69431eaec0b1::"
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: That looked like a real API key?!

Comment: The auth token usually is the bearer token to for IBM Cloud.

Comment: @data_henrik Sorry where do i find the bearer token for IBM COS? is that apikey field in the json?

Answer (score 1):

The bearer token is from IAM.
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/getting-started-cli.html#gather-key-information

See this doc on generating pre-signed urls (temporary).
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/api-reference/api-reference-objects.html#object-operations

Comment: Thank you for response. I can able to get the bearer token from the first link you have provided. But not sure Which pre-signed URLs to be used from the object operations document ?

Comment: Under **Upload an object**
1. set the HMAC headers      Sample request (HMAC Headers)
2. create the pre-signed url    Sample request (HMAC Pre-signed URL)

Answer (score 0):

To do a one-off request like that, you can get oauth tokens from the command line using `ibmcloud iam oauth-tokens`. To specifically get an IAM Token, I use:

`` export IAM_TOKEN=`ibmcloud iam oauth-tokens | head -n 1 | awk ' {print $4} '` ``

Then follow that up with your cURL command:

`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $IAM_TOKEN" ...`

An application should request tokens based on the apiKey as mentioned.

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d 'apikey=<your api key here>&grant_type=urn:ibm:params:oauth:grant-type:apikey' "https://iam.bluemix.net/identity/token"`

Here's an example using NPM's request-promise:

```js
const response = await rp({
  url: 'https://iam.bluemix.net/identity/token',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
  method: "POST",
  body: `apikey=${apiKey}&grant_type=urn%3Aibm%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Aapikey`,
  json: true
});

const token = response.access_token;
```